# How to declare the windowinterophelper for usercontrol in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net

How to Pass The user control object to the WindowInteropHelper.
because i am using TWAIN all For scan Functionality. i want to pass the user control object to the WindowInteropHelper so how to pass the user control object. :(

```
_interopHelper = new WindowInteropHelper(UserControlObj); 'It Gives Error when i am passing the UserConrol Object.its accepts Window.
```

Comment: Not at all. A UserControl is not a Window, so you can't pass it to WindowInteropHelper.

Comment: Thank You For You Valuable Replay. OK,Then how to convert User Control to Window ? :( Or USer Control Having Any InteropHelper ?

Comment: You can't convert a UserControl to a Window because it isn't a window. It's a totally different kind of control.